# delete N lines before if find matches in Notepad++

Tags: regex, text, replace, notepad++

I want to delete 3 lines upwards if find matches in notepad++ using regular expression

Example

```
LINE 1
LINE 2

LINE 3
LINE 4
LINE 5

LINE 6
LINE 7
```

If regular expression match `LINE 5` then output has to be like be

```
LINE 1
LINE 2



LINE 6
LINE 7
```

I have tried with many replace pattern but no success. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Can you post what your regex attempt?

Comment: @drum in Notepad++ Find Column `LINE 5` Replace column `\3\r\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/O7K3GZ/1)

```
.*\n.*\nLINE 5
```

Description

```
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
  * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
  * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
LINE 5 matches the characters LINE 5 literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Depending on the system, it may be necessary to use `\r` or `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @abc123 Thanks for your reply. I want to do it in Notepad++, as per your answer i have used like in Find column entered `LINE 5` in Replace column i entered `.*\r\n.*\r\n`, but it didn't give expected result.

Comment: @sujin You should enter `.*\r\n.*\r\nLINE 5` in Find and leave Replace empty.

Comment: It can be also written as `(?:.*\n){2}LINE 5` for easier maintenance like changing the number of lines and the symbol of new line.

Comment: Thanks @EganWolf .It worked perfect. `(?:.*\n){2}LINE 5` this one is cool.